# переводчик на java

Tags: java, swing

мне надо написать переводчик на java, но чет не получается...
когда по идее функция readProperties должна return'ить значение, она выводит вместо него null, даже если слово правильное.

имеется словарь,

содержание типа:

слово = шифровка слова

класс GUI:

```
package ru.myrk.pebucshifting.translator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
class GUI{
  public GUI(){
    JFrame win = new JFrame("PebucShifting TRANSLATOR");
    win.setSize(320,100);
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,0,0));

    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    JButton go = new JButton("Translate!");
    File file;
    JLabel translated_text=new JLabel("none");

    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    file=fc.getSelectedFile();

    win.add(text);
    win.add(go);
    win.add(translated_text);
    win.setVisible(true);

    Functions f=new Functions();

    //some events...
    go.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String gottext = text.toString();
        String[] words = gottext.split(" ");
        String ended_sentence="";
        for (int i = 0; i<words.length;i++){
          ended_sentence += f.readProperties(file,"макс");
        }
        gottext = ended_sentence;
        translated_text.setText(gottext);
      }
    });
    //end of some events

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
       new GUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

класс Functions:

```
package ru.myrk.pebucshifting.translator;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class Functions{
    public String readProperties(File file,String name) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(fis);

            return props.getProperty(name);
        } catch (IOException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", 0);}
        catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        return "none";
    }
    }
```

Comment: пора использовать FX

Comment: Поставьте брейк-поинты в этом методе и посмотрите, что именно происходит во время выполнения

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){ /*
Здесь у вас происходит событие нажатия на кнопку "Translate!"
Вам нужно считать все слова из выбранного вами файла и уже потом обрабатывать их. 
*/